# NetTrain an image caption generator

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I would like to write out the simplest possible word-by-word ***image caption generator***. This network should take an image and build a sentence describing it.

Here is my [fashion dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cq6bem7m6rr149p/fashion_captions.wdx?dl=0) of images and their string captions. You can download and import it:

```
Import @ "fashion_captions.wdx"
```

I need a little help getting the network and training mechanics worked out. Here's my code (and a toy dataset for now) - the definitions of `makeDecoderRNN` and `trainingNet` are not right:

```
vocabSize = 40236; (* from NetEncoder["Tokens"] *)    
embedSize = 50; (* arbitrary for now*)

data = Table[<| 
    "Input" -> RandomImage[1, {224, 224}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"], 
    "Output" -> StringRiffle[RandomWord[5]]|>, 2];

resnet152 = 
  NetTake[NetModel[
    "ResNet-152 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"], {1, -2}];

makeEncoderCNN[embedSize_] := NetInitialize @ NetChain[
   {resnet152, LinearLayer[embedSize],  BatchNormalizationLayer[]}]

makeDecoderRNN[embedSize_, vocabSize_, lstmSize_: 50, lstmLayers_: 5] := 
  NetInitialize @ NetGraph[<|     
    "lstm" -> NetChain[
       Table[LongShortTermMemoryLayer[lstmSize], lstmLayers]],
    "last" -> SequenceLastLayer[],
    "linear" -> LinearLayer[vocabSize],
    "soft" -> SoftmaxLayer[]
    |>, {
       NetPort["ImageFeatures"] -> NetPort["lstm", {1, "State"}],
       "lstm" -> "last" -> "linear" -> "soft"
    },
   "ImageFeatures" -> embedSize,
   "Output" -> NetDecoder["Tokens"]
   ]

traningNet = NetGraph[
  <|"cnn" -> makeEncoderCNN[embedSize],
   "rnn" -> makeDecoderRNN[embedSize, vocabSize]|>,
  {"cnn" -> NetPort["rnn", "ImageFeatures"]}
  ]

NetTrain[traningNet, data]
```

Here's a picture of one version of the basic thing I'm trying to implement:

[image]

And this is the paper (minus the attention): *Show, Attend and Tell: Neural Image Caption Generation with Visual Attention, 2015.* I was trying to follow.

The key idea is you somehow inject the image's features into an rnn and iterate one timestep on x0 (start token) trying to output the target y0 (the first word in the caption) then feed that next state and y0 to get y1 (the second word) etc.

Anyhow, I think that there's a NetFoldOperator missing somewhere and may have to use CTC loss?

**Links:**

- A good image captioning [tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/building-an-image-caption-generator-with-deep-learning-in-tensorflow-a142722e9b1f) in pytorch
- https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/tree/master/tutorials/03-advanced/image_captioning
- https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-caption-photos-with-deep-learning/

**Example Data:**

- CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a6912225-dbf9-4951-ba98-161b013104b9"]

Answer (score 9):

```
enc = NetGraph[
  {
   NetTake[NetModel["ResNet-152 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"], {1, -2}]
   },
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> 1 -> NetPort["State"]
   }
  ]
```

[image]

For example, we have 100 tokens + 2 reserved (101 = start of sequence, 102 = end of sequence).

```
dec = NetGraph[
   {
    EmbeddingLayer[10, 100 + 2],
    SequenceMostLayer[],
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[1000],
    NetMapOperator[{LinearLayer[100 + 2], SoftmaxLayer[]}]
    },
   {
    NetPort["Input"] -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4,
    NetPort["State"] -> NetPort[3, "State"]
    }
   ] // NetInitialize
```

[image]

```
net = NetGraph[
  <|
   "enc" -> enc,
   "dec" -> dec,
   "loss" -> CrossEntropyLossLayer["Index"],
   "rest" -> SequenceRestLayer[]
   |>,
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> "enc",
   NetPort["enc", "State"] -> NetPort["dec", "State"],
   NetPort["Target"] -> NetPort["dec", "Input"],
   "dec" -> NetPort["loss", "Input"],
   NetPort["Target"] -> "rest" -> NetPort["loss", "Target"]
   },
  "Target" -> {"Varying", "Integer"}
  ]
```

[image]

```
data = Table[
   RandomImage[1, {224, 224}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"] -> 
    Join[{101}, RandomChoice[Range[100], RandomChoice@Range[10]], {102}],
   {100}
   ];

data[[;; 2]]
```

[image]

```
predict[input_] := Module[
  {enc, dec, sobj},
  enc = NetReplacePart[NetExtract[netT, "enc"], 
     "Input" -> 
      NetEncoder[{"Image", {224, 224}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}]]@input;
  dec = RightComposition[
     NetDelete[#, 2] &,
     NetTake[#, {NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Output"]}] &,
     NetReplacePart[#, 
       "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[100 + 2]}]] &
     ]@NetExtract[netT, "dec"];
  sobj = NetStateObject[
    NetTake[dec, {NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Output"]}],
    <|
     {2, "State"} -> enc
     |>
    ];
  Rest@Flatten@NestWhileList[sobj, {101}, # != {102} &, 1, 20]
  ]
```

Quickly check results with untrained network.

```
netT = net;

predict /@ data[[;; 2, 1]]
```

> {{24, 24, 24, 24, 13, 15, 15, 50, 50, 20, 20, 20, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8}, {24, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 50, 50, 50, 50, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8}}

Train the network.

```
netT = NetTrain[
  net,
  <|"Input" -> data[[;; , 1]], "Target" -> data[[;; , 2]]|>,
  LearningRateMultipliers -> {"enc" -> None, _ -> 1}
  ]
```

Comment: This is wonderful Alexey! I'm confused on how to use word tokens instead of integers "Target" -> {"Varying", "Token"}  doesn't work for me. I added an example dataset to the post.

Comment: I've added a dropbox link to the full dataset (in wdx format) of fashion image -> captions that I'd like to train it on, please take a look if you can.

Comment: With `NetEncoder[{"Characters", {Automatic, StartOfString, EndOfString}}]` we can encode start and end of sequence. With `NetEncoder["Tokens"]` we cannot. We need separate encoder and decoder. Encoder: `e[str_String]:=Join[(*start of sequence*){40237},NetEncoder[{"Tokens","English","IgnoreCase"->True}]@str,(*end of sequence*){40238}]` Decoder: `d[list_List] := NetDecoder["Tokens"]@Map[UnitVector[40238, #] &, list]`

Comment: In `dec` and `predict` replace 100 with 40236. The rest of the code is unchanged. `data=CloudGet[...]` Then `predict@data[[1]]["Input"]//d` will return text. For training: `netT=NetTrain[net,<|"Input"->data[[;;,1]],"Target"->e/@data[[;;,2]]|>,...]`